# How to use REGEXP in a constraint which requires input to be 2 characters and 2 number

Tags: oracle, constraints

I need the input to be in the form of XX##
where the X are letters and the # are numbers.

This is what ive got so far which doesnt seem to work.

```
CREATE TABLE videoTable(
videoID number PRIMARY KEY,
channelID number,
videoTitle VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
videoPostedDate DATE NOT NULL,
videoTags VARCHAR(255) NULL,
noViews number NOT NULL,
videoCode VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  c_videoCode check(videoCode REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+$')
);
```

Current Error:

```
CONSTRAINT      c_videoCode check(videoCode REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+$')
                                            *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `REGEXP`, but it does have `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(videoCode, '^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+$'))
```

Note that `REGEXP` is not Oracle syntax, it is MySQL.  And if you are really using MySQL, check constraints won't work unless you are using version 8 or later.

Comment: I just tried that and was thrown this error. ```CONSTRAINT      c_videoCode check(videoCode REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+$')
                                            *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Ill add it to the original question

Comment: @RossKnight My answer is _not_ using `REGEXP`, which is a MySQL operator, it is using `REGEXP_LIKE`.